# Building BI over indoor micro-location data

Tags: ibeacon

We will soon be logging indoor micro-location data gathered through iBeacon deployments and client Apps, into our database and we are now beginning to explore what tools are available to build BI information on the persisted data, such as:

(Some of these are easy enough to build through SQL queries, but we would like to know if there are any vendors that provide more interesting info, in an efficient manner especially as the data size gets bigger and bigger).

- Which aisles attract most traffic?
- What is the most traversed path?
- In which aisles do people spend most of their time?
- etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather unfocused question, but basically you are talking about big data analytics. A good place to start thinking about how you will manage and process your data would be to look at the [Apache Hadoop project](http://hadoop.apache.org) and associated projects.